# including multiple html pages in one page utilizing JavaScript from main page

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to include several html pages on one page and have it utilize the JavaScript on the main page? I have a tabbed page and on one page it is rather large. I was hoping that I could just include the page in the tab section on the main page. It does load the page but it only lets the first page that loads use the JavaScript. If I comment the first include out the next page has access to the Javascript. Is there something i am missing here or is it just not possible?

I have tried 2 different methods of including and this is the one that seems to work but still has the above issue..

```
    <script>
    function includeHTML() {
        var z, i, elmnt, file, xhttp;
        /*loop through a collection of all HTML elements:*/
        z = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
        for (i = 0; i < z.length; i++) {
            elmnt = z[i];
            /*search for elements with a certain atrribute:*/
            file = elmnt.getAttribute("w3-include-html");
            if (file) {
                /*make an HTTP request using the attribute value as the file name:*/
                xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                    if (this.readyState == 4) {
                        if (this.status == 200) { elmnt.innerHTML = this.responseText; }
                        if (this.status == 404) { elmnt.innerHTML = "Page not found."; }
                        /*remove the attribute, and call this function once more:*/
                        elmnt.removeAttribute("w3-include-html");
                        includeHTML();
                    }
                }
                xhttp.open("GET", file, true);
                xhttp.send();
                /*exit the function:*/
                return;
            }
        }
    };

    includeHTML();

</script>

<div w3-include-html="ManualMotion.html"></div>
```

The second method is this, it loads the page but none of the pages work from the JavaScript..

```
$(function(){
     $("#loadSpacer").load("LoadSpacer.html");
     $("#manualMotion").load("ManualMotion.html");
 });


<div id="manualMotion"></div>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: _"Is it possible to include several html pages on one page [...?]"_ - It's far from the most elegant solution, but the _quick and dirty_ approach is to use `<iframe>`.

Comment: At some point it would have to be viewed on an IPAD so <iframe> would not work unless they now support that. I have not looked into it lately..

Comment: I'm not absolutely sure, but it looks like `position: absolute` may fix the iframe scrolling issue in Safari Mobile. (See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43262156/cant-scroll-iframe-on-mobile-ios-safari). I don't want to defend the `<iframe>` approach too much, because, I agree with you, a scripted solution would be more elegant. You could, alternatively, try the [HTML Import SHIM](https://github.com/RouninMedia/HTML-Import-SHIM) approach which reaches into a temporarily displayed `<iframe>` and adds all or some of the iframed DOM into the parent document's DOM.